# How to design a table component that stores data and also includes HTML code

Tags: design, front-end, vue.js

###### I am developing a front end application given a back end with some API.

The application has two  **similar**  views. Both views make use of a big  **table**  that's also used as a  **form** . For example, in the table there are some values which are inputs or check boxes, or even buttons. That table also comes with a nice search in table functionality.

So I thought I would just make a  **new component**  and share it between the views. But since then I have been losing my mind over how I would make a clean design that's  **not hard to use** .

What I have thought:

The component would take the  **objects and the attributes**  of the objects we want it to display  **as input**  (via props) and that's in common between of all my thoughts. Then to display the check boxes/inputs/buttons etc. it could do one of the following:

1. It would use  **dynamic slots**  (e.g extraRow1, extraRow2, extraRow3 ...) to insert templates of HTML containing every HTML column in every row. 
   For example:

   ```
   component.vue
   <template>
       <tr v-for=...>
           <td v-for=... >
               attributes of objects here, NON HTML
           </td>
           <slot v-for= ... :name=`extraRow${i}`>
       </tr>
   </template>
   ```

   ```
   parent.vue
   <template>
      <component objects=... attributesWanted=...>
          <template v-for=... #[`extraRow${i}`]>
               <!-- First Column -->
               <td> <input type='checkbox'> </input> </td>
                ...            
          </template>
      </component>
   </template>
   ```

   Feels really hacky/dirty though, I feel shame writing that pseudo-code.
2. Could pass the  **raw HTMLs in an array**  and go through it in component using v-for and v-html directives.

Of course, in both cases, if a button or submit input is activated the component could either active the parent method directly (even more coupling) or fire an event.

The reason I am here is that I don't feel proud for any of the solutions, because as you can notice are really poor.

Do you have any better solutions, do you think I shouldn't even use a component?

Comment: I don't see a concrete argument against the more straightforward approach of keeping the HTML in the actual web app where it belongs. Sure, there are some exceptions to this (e.g. rich text), but I see no relevant exception here. While I'm no Vue expert by any means, the trivial nature of sharing a component across multiple views makes me suspect that you're not using Vue the way it is designed to be used, and the answer to your question is better given via a Vue tutorial on how to create and integrate subcomponents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time searching, I finally found myself an answer. The answer was inspired by  [Vue Bootstrap](https://bootstrap-vue.org/) 's tables.

For each row, in each column the table should use a slot named "column($columnName)" providing the traversal object to parent using scoped slots, and have fall back the objects[columnName] value.

Code for parent and component is demonstrated below:

MyTable.vue

```html
<script>
    import { defineComponent } from "vue";

    export default defineComponent({
        props: ["objects", "fields"],
        data() {
            return {
                
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<template>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td v-for="field of fields">
                {{ field }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="object of objects">
            <td v-for="field of fields">
                <slot :name="`column(${field})`" :object="object">
                    {{ object[field] }}
                </slot>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</template>
```

Parent.vue

```html
<script>
    import { defineComponent } from "vue";
    import MyTable from "./components/MyTable.vue";

    export default defineComponent({
    data() {
        return {
            objects: [
                {
                    firstName: "Bob",
                    lastName: "Marley",
                    email: "bobmarley@gmail.com"
                },
                {
                    firstName: "John",
                    lastName: "Doe",
                    email: "jonedoe@hotmail.com"
                }
            ],
            fields: ["firstName", "lastName", "email", "deleteButtons"]
        };
    },
    components: { MyTable }
});
</script>

<template>
    <my-table :objects="objects" :fields="fields"> 
        <template #column(deleteButtons)="{object}">
            <button>
                Delete {{ object.firstName }}
            </button>
        </template>
    </my-table>
</template>
```

Result:

[image: The result of the code]